# Dart and third party library integration

Tags: javascript, dart, integration

I have simple example of usage of some map library

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://api4.mapy.cz/loader.js"></script>
    <script>Loader.load()</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapa" style="width:600px; height:400px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var stred = SMap.Coords.fromWGS84(14.41, 50.08);
        var mapa = new SMap(JAK.gel("mapa"), stred, 10);
        mapa.addDefaultLayer(SMap.DEF_BASE).enable();
        mapa.addDefaultControls();                
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How am I supposed to integrate this in Dart. I feel myself weak in javascript so I'm seeking any option how to get rid of javascript use, but I always fail when integrate with 3rd part libraries. I tried with GWT, the last version is using backbone, but it is mess. So I'm giving Dart a chance now, but it is hopeless so far.

I tried something like this

```
 var stred = context['SMap']['Coords'].callMethod('fromWGS84', [14.41, 50.08]);
 var element = context['JAK'].callMethod('gel', 'mapa');
 var mapa = new JsObject(context['SMap'],[[element], [stred], 10]);
```

First line seems to make it, but after it stops, undefined and usual javascript madness, debuging dart.js is like javascript hell squared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to produce the same result as your JS code:

```dart
  var stred = context['SMap']['Coords'].callMethod('fromWGS84', [14.41, 50.08]);
  var element = context['JAK'].callMethod('gel', ['mapa']);
  var mapa = new JsObject(context['SMap'],[element, stred, 10]);
  mapa.callMethod('addDefaultLayer', [context['SMap']['DEF_BASE']])
      .callMethod('enable', []);
  mapa.callMethod('addDefaultControls', []);
```

Comment: so we are one line further `var stred = context['SMap']['Coords'].callMethod('fromWGS84', [14.41, 50.08]);
 var element = context['JAK'].callMethod('gel', ['mapa']);
 var mapa = new JsObject(context['SMap'],[[element], [stred], 10]);


 mapa.callMethod('addDefaultLayer', [context['SMap']['DEF_BASE']]).callMethod('enable');
 mapa.callMethod('addDefaultControls');`

Comment: Great, it works, starting to like Dart more and more, thank you very much you have gave me big "feasibility" kick thanks

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help :-). As far as I know there is work in progress to make dart-js-interop even easier but I'm not up-to-date about the current progress or status.